# What is the cofinality of $\kappa^{<\kappa}$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I am not sure if this has been answered before, but I did not find anything.

**Definition** $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\sup\{\kappa^\lambda\mid\lambda<\kappa\}$.

Assume $\kappa$ to be limit and singular. What do we know about the cofinality of $\kappa^{<\kappa}$?

Comment: These comments have been removed, as meta issues are off-topic here. Please open a thread on meta if you wish to continue this line of discussion.

Comment: I guess the exponentiation here is cardinal exponentiation? It's not clear in the question.

Comment: @user21820: Yes, what else could it be?

Comment: Ordinal exponentiation? It's still a possible question, even if much easier than for cardinal exponentiation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $\kappa$ is a singular cardinal. To analyze the size of $\kappa^{<\kappa}$, there are two cases to consider: either

1. the function $\rho\mapsto\kappa^\rho$ eventually stabilizes below $\kappa$, that is, there is a $\tau<\kappa$ such that for all $\rho$ with $\tau\le\rho<\kappa$ we have $\kappa^\rho=\kappa^\tau$, or else
2. case 1. fails, that is, the function $\rho\mapsto\kappa^\rho$ is strictly increasing on a cofinal set of cardinals below $\kappa$.

In case 2., obviously $\kappa^{<\kappa}$ has cofinality $\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$.

Let's now consider case 1. We argue that $\kappa^{<\kappa}=2^\kappa$ in this case. It follows that its cofinality is strictly larger than $\kappa$, and we cannot really say more.

To prove the equality, first we prove the lemma that, in general,
$$2^\lambda=(2^{<\lambda})^{\mathrm{cf}(\lambda)}.$$
This is obvious if $\lambda$ is a successor, so it suffices to consider the case where $\lambda$ is limit. Consider a strictly increasing sequence $(\lambda_\alpha)_{\alpha<\mathrm{cf}(\lambda)}$ cofinal in $\lambda$. We have $$2^\lambda=2^{\sum_\alpha \lambda_\alpha}=\prod_\alpha 2^{\lambda_\alpha}\le(2^{<\lambda})^{\mathrm{cf}(\lambda)},$$ and the other inequality is clear.

Returning to case 1., there are again two options: (a) If for some $\rho<\kappa$ we have $2^\rho\ge\kappa$ then $\kappa^\rho=2^\rho$. Since we are in case 1., it follows that in this situation the function $\rho\mapsto2^\rho$ eventually stabilizes below $\kappa$, and of course $\kappa^{<\kappa}$ is also equal to this value. In this case, $2^\kappa$ is also equal to this common value, by the lemma, and we are done.

(b) Otherwise, $\rho<\kappa$ implies $2^\rho<\kappa$, that is, $\kappa$ is a strong limit singular cardinal. In this case, $2^\kappa=\kappa^{\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)}$, by the lemma. Since $\kappa^\kappa=2^\kappa$, it follows that $\kappa^{<\kappa}=\kappa^{\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)}$ and again we are done.

---

Let me conclude by pointing out that all cases mentioned in the analysis above are possible:

Case 2 is realized for $\kappa=\aleph_\omega$ if $2^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{\omega+n+1}$ for all $n<\omega$. This can be easily achieved starting with a model of $\mathsf{GCH}$ and using Easton forcing. In this case we have $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_n}=2^{\aleph_n}$ for all $n$ (and $\aleph_\omega^{<\aleph_\omega}=\aleph_{\omega+\omega}$ has cofinality $\omega=\mathrm{cf}(\aleph_\omega)$).

One may be curious whether this can be improved to have $\aleph_\omega$ strong limit and $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}<\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_1}<\dots\,$. It turns out this is not possible, as proved independently by Hajnal and Shelah. Indeed, if $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are infinite cardinals and $2^{<\lambda}\le\kappa$, then $\{\kappa^\rho\mid \rho<\lambda\}$ is finite. I learned this as Theorem 1.5 in

> [MR0991617](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=991617). Monk, J. Donald. *Appendix on set theory*. In **Handbook of Boolean algebras, Vol. 3**, 1213–1233, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1989.

(I looked at this appendix just now, to find the precise reference, and it seems to me that it also contains enough information to reconstruct my answer.)

Case 1.(a) is possible by starting with a model of $\mathsf{GCH}$ and forcing $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_\omega}=\aleph_{\omega+1}$, simply by adding Cohen reals. In this case we have $\aleph_\omega^{<\aleph_\omega}=\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_n}=\aleph_{\omega+1}$ for all $n$ (a regular cardinal).

We could have just as easily added many more Cohen reals and get, say, $2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_\omega}=\aleph_{\omega_{\omega+3}}$, which now makes $\aleph_\omega^{<\aleph_\omega}$ a singular cardinal of cofinality $\aleph_{\omega+3}$.

Case 1.(b) holds under $\mathsf{GCH}$. Under appropriate large cardinal assumptions, we can make life more interesting by forcing a violation of the singular cardinal hypothesis at $\aleph_\omega$ (while keeping $\aleph_\omega$ strong limit). There are now some limitations, coming from Shelah's pcf theory but, for instance, we can have $\aleph_\omega$ strong limit and $2^{\aleph_\omega}=\aleph_\omega^{<\aleph_\omega}=\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ for any infinite countable ordinal $\alpha$, as shown in

> [MR0823777 (87b:03114)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=823777). Shelah, Saharon. *[The singular cardinals problem: independence results](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511758867.004)*. In **Surveys in set theory**, 116–134,
> London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 87, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 1983.

Pcf theory tells us we cannot get $\alpha$ above to be $\aleph_4$ or higher, but the picture here is still far from clear.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (and this might be a good addition to the last paragraph), it is consistent (modulo large cardinals) that $\alpha$ is arbitrarily high below $\omega_1$. No?

Comment: Hi Asaf, yes, that's what I said right before the last reference: $\alpha$ can be any infinite countable ordinal.

Comment: Okay, I guess it's time to get some sleep. :)

Comment: :-)${{{}}}{{}}$

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo. Thank you. Your answer is very thorough. It always surprises me how easily you can ask cardinal arithmetic questions that are hard to answer. I refer to the second part of your answer, not the first.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo. One more clarification. Is it true that if we add $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ Cohen reals then $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ also equals $\aleph_{\omega+1}$? What if $2^{\aleph_1}$ is much bigger?

Comment: Hi Ioanni. If we start with a model of $\mathsf{GCH}$ and all we do is add $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ Cohen reals, then yes, $2^{\aleph_{\omega}}=\aleph_{\omega+1}$. But of course we can add $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ Cohen reals and $\aleph_{\omega_7}$ Cohen subsets of $\aleph_1$ and $\aleph_{\omega_{43}+3}$ subsets of $\aleph_2$, and then $2^{\aleph_{\omega}}=\aleph_{\omega_{43}+3}$ as well. In general, if we add sets to the $\aleph_n$, the size of $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ will be the smallest size consistent with the fact that the exponential is monotone and with König's theorem.

Comment: (That is the example I give illustrating Case 2.) If we want to make $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ larger than this smallest possible size, then things get significantly more complicated, as this means we would be violating the singular cardinal hypothesis.

Comment: And I agree with you, that seemingly simple cardinal arithmetic questions lead frequently to unexpectedly deep and fascinating results. This is true in both directions: when we manage to prove theorems and when we manage to establish consistency results. It is a topic that has intrigued me for years. My [undergraduate thesis](https://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/andres-eduardo-caicedo-el-problema-de-los-cardinales-singulares.pdf) was precisely on the singular cardinal hypothesis.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo. I have to learn Spanish to read your thesis now!  On the other hand I am impressed by the topics: L, forcing, $0^{\#}$, core models. Not the typical topics of an undergraduate thesis. That's for sure.

Comment: Thanks. It is a bit awkward and dated now, as you can imagine, but I still consult it when I have to do some quick cardinal arithmetic computations; that part has aged better than the rest. :-)