# Show $\aleph_\omega^\omega>\aleph_\omega$

Tags: set-theory

Show $\aleph_\omega^\omega>\aleph_\omega$.

$\aleph_\omega=\bigcup_{n=0}^\omega\aleph_n$.

$\aleph_\omega^\omega$ is the set of all functions from $\omega$ to $\aleph_\omega$.

I know that $2^{\aleph_\omega}> \aleph_\omega$.
But I can’t show that $\aleph_\omega^\omega\geq 2^{\aleph_\omega}$.

Comment: Are you familiar with Konig’s Theorem?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2457440/how-to-evaluate-prod-i-in-omega-aleph-i/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prove this by diagonalization. Let $\{f_\alpha:\alpha < \omega_\omega\}$ be a collection of size $\aleph_\omega,$ consisting of functions $f_\alpha : \omega\to \omega_\omega.$ Then let $f(n)$ be the least ordinal not in $\{f_\alpha(n) : \alpha < \omega_n\},$ which is surely less than $\omega_\omega,$ since that set has smaller cardinality than $\omega_\omega.$ Then $f:\omega\to \omega_\omega$ and $f\ne f_\alpha$ for any $\alpha<\omega_\omega.$

You can also use [Konig's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory)) (which arguably has the downside of using choice unnecessarily). $$ \aleph_\omega = \sum_{n<\omega}\aleph_n <\prod_{n<\omega}\aleph_\omega = \aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}$$